# Asus Transformer TF101 keyboard not working when docked

Tags: keyboard, asus-eee-pad-transformer, docking-station

I have an Asus EEE Pad Transformer TF101 Android tablet and docking station. It came with Android v3.2 installed, and I have since then upgraded OTA to 4.0.

I haven't used the dock much but it used to work. Recently I did a factory reset, because I intend to sell this. But now, the physical keyboard of the docking station is not working. The tablet shows the docked indicator when docked. The touchpad works. The extra battery works. The USB ports work, but not the keyboard. The virtual keyboard is showing `hardware keyboard ON` when docked but keypresses does nothing. If I move the slider to OFF then the virtual keyboard is working.

I have reset a few times now and the same issue remains. What happened, and how can I try to fix this?